# How to remove a string in slist

Tags: c++

I am new in STL and facing problem in slist.
I have a slistalist.I need to remove a last entry of a string suppose "Version" from this slist.
How can i do that.

Comment: this slist is of type string :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are your facing that official documentation can't solved?

Comment: please specify what is slist?

Comment: What i did is to store this slist <string> to a string using --  string repairText = alist.front;int pos = alist.find_last_of("version"); repairText.erase(repairText.begin() + pos, repairText.end());

Comment: @sarathi http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html

Comment: Post a minimal, but complete, code that reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: Probably `"version"` is not found in `repairText`. Have you tried `if (pos != string::npos) repairText.erase(repairText.begin() + pos, repairText.end());`. This seems to be a question about the string class, not the slist class. Also note that you are modifying a *copy* of the string in your slist, the original will be unchanged.

Comment: What dies it mean "this slist is of type string"? Do you nean you are using `std::slist<std::string>` or do you mean you the type is `std::string` and there isn't any `std::slist<T>` involved?

Answer (score 1):

For `std::slist<T>` you can't erase the element an iterator points to directly. You'll need to find the element preceding it instead. To find the first element to erase I would use `std::adjacent_find()` and ignore the first argument in the predicate:

```
void erase_value(T const& value, std::slist<T>& l) {
    auto it = std::adjacent_find(l.begin(), l.end(),
        [=](T const&, T const& v) {
            return v == value;
        });
    if (it != l.end()) {
        l.erase_after(it);
    }
}
```

To remove the last element you need to keep finding, remebering the previously found element and just remove the last found element. That is, find the first element and then, while there are potentially more, keep finding.